# Early stopping ray.tune experiments when complex conditions are met?

Tags: ray

Is there a way of stopping `ray.tune` experiments (for example using PBT) when clearly overfitting or the one metric did not improve for a long time?

Comment: we're adding fancier stopping criteria per trial in this PR - https://github.com/ray-project/ray/pull/4468; if this doesn't fit your use case, can you tell me more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: @richliaw Yep, this is exactly what I'd need. Do you have an ETA for the release that will contain this? Also, ray is awesome, thanks for the work!

Comment: Probably in 2 weeks? One workaround you can do right now is manually setting some quantity that measures improvement or overfitting, and then setting a stopping criteria to kill the task if the quantity is too high.

Answer (score 0):

This is now well-supported in Tune with https://github.com/ray-project/ray/pull/12750.

Check out the docs here: https://docs.ray.io/en/master/tune/api_docs/stoppers.html#stopping-mechanisms-tune-stopper

For example:

```
tune.run(Trainable, num_samples=200, stop=TimeStopper())
```